# Python create function that automatically creates variable within function that calls it?

Tags: python

So let's say I have this function with a lot of variable setting:

```
def set_variables():
    var_a = 10
    var_b = 200
```

and these variables need to be set in multiple functions and accessed via their var name. Is there a way to create this function s.t. after it's  call the parent function that calls it has `var_a` and `var_b` without having to return them? The function above is an example, but in reality there are a lot of variables so it's not really viable to have something like the below.

```
def parent_function():
   var_a, var_b, ... = set_variables()
```

ideally I'd like something like

```
def parent_function():
   set_variables()
   # do some code with var_a or var_b
```

Or maybe even return a dict of `key`, `val` and automatically generate variables of `key` name set to `val`.

So for example

```
def parent_function():
    var_dict = set_variables()
    some_func_to_auto_set_vars_from_dict(var_dict)
    # Do something with var_a or var_b
```

Comment: You can create global variables in a function, but you can't create local variables for one function in a separate function, if that is what you are trying to do.

Comment: You are looking for dynamically scoped variables: Python is *lexically* scoped. What you want isn't possible.

Comment: If your def is member of a class you have options (class and instance variables).

Comment: If you are willing to have `set_variables` return a value, just return a single `dict` instead of multiple values.

Comment: I think more than likely what I want is not possible, but I thought I'd ask

Comment: Use a dict or a NamedTuple IMO.

Comment: @chepner is there a way to automatically pop the dictionary values to variables named their key?

Comment: This seems like a great time to start learning about object oriented programming.

Comment: If you're opposed to OOP, is there any particular reason at least that you don't just use parameters in your function definitions? If `set_variables()` were to simply return whatever variables necessary, you could then just pass those variables to `parent_function()`.

Answer (score 1):

Return a collection that lets you access the values by name without having to re-assign them, e.g. a dict:

```
def set_variables():
    return {
        'a': 10,
        'b': 200,
    }
```

```
def parent_function():
   v = set_variables()
   # do some code with v['a'] or v['b']
```

Or (my personal preference for this use case) a `NamedTuple`, which gives you the benefit of type checking (and IDE autocomplete, exactly as if you were using top-level named vars):

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class Vars(NamedTuple):
    a: int
    b: int

def set_variables() -> Vars:
    return Vars(a=10, b=200)

def parent_function():
    v = set_variables()
    # do some code with v.a and v.b
```

Comment: is there a way in `parent_function` to convert the dict to variables named after the `key` in dict with value `val`

Comment: Use `NamedTuple` IMO -- expanded answer a bit to show how that works.

Comment: Just a heads up, `vars` is a built-in function that you're shadowing.

Answer (score 0):

It may seem easy to let all functions set all variables.  But this implicit sharing of state has proven to become a maintenance nightmare.

Rather, use immutable dataclasses; they provide more or less the convenience you request, but allow for much easier reasoning about the code.

```
@dataclass
class Settings:
  a: str =""
  b: int =5
  ...

def parent():
  s = initialize(Settings(c=[1,2,3]))
  use(s.a, s.b)
  ...

def initialize (s: Settings):
  return dataclass.replace(s,
      b=10, d="@#$_"
    )
```